# Why is the timeout not respected in this pipeline

Tags: azure-pipelines

I want to set the timeout to 3 hours for the following pipeline, but it times out after 1 hour

```
jobs:
- job:
  pool:
    vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
  timeoutInMinutes: 180
  displayName: 'Running test'
  steps:
  - bash: |
     .....
```

times out after 60 mins

Answer (score 0):

I assume 60 minutes is the limit for the hosted agent in private repos. So job cant run longer

[image]

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/phases?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#timeouts